Why is my GitHub workflow running on every push even if there are not new changes to files defined in the paths?
I want my workflow to execute in the following scenario:

If specific files are changed in the commit thats pushed
Its a PR
The PR opened against main branch

So when a new PR is opened with changes to my files I want it to run. But I don't want it to run on subsequent pushes to the PR unless those commits have new changes to those files.
Is this possible? This seems like pretty basic behavior, but I can't figure out the right config.
I have this:
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - myfolder/fileone.json
      - myfolder/filetwo.json
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - myfolder/fileone.json
      - myfolder/filetwo.json

This runs when PR is opened and there are changes to the files, but it also runs on every single push after that even if the push doesn't include additional changes to the files.
Edit
Possible solution per user comments:
on:
  # Run if files from "paths:" change when PR first opened against main
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - myfolder/fileone.json
      - myfolder/filetwo.json
  # Run on every subsequent push to main only if push includes changes in files in "paths:"
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - myfolder/fileone.json
      - myfolder/filetwo.json

When branch is merged into main it also runs because a merged PR will always create a push event to the branch it's being merged onto.

I believe the pull_request event looks at the diff to the base branch. If you only keep the push trigger, but remove the branches filter, does that do what you want?

Notice that for pull_request, CI/CD actually runs on a "test merge", taking into account changes in the base branch; using just push would drop that behaviour, so you wouldn't actually test the post-merge state.

But if I remove pull_request it wont run when the PR is first opened right? I need that to happen.

You could add pull_request on type opened additionally

@BenjaminW. can you confirm my "possible solution" is correct? You could also add it as an answer so I can mark it.

So I tried this and it actually doesn't work. When a new PR is opened my workflow does not run at all when those files are modified.

You can't limit push to main, as a PR into main by definition doesn't run on main. You should drop the branches filter on the push event.

As a caveat, this might not let you make merging conditional on the workflow result, as the push event isn't directly linked to any specific pull request.
